# CSS problem about show / hide

Tags: css

I have realized show/hide function in css. But it's not what i need. i want to expand the content layer by layer and hide them all in one click. And now i can't expand layer by layer.

Can you help me with that? Thanks a lot. :)

here is the code and it's tested:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(id) {
        var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
            if (state == 'block') {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
</script>
 <style type="text/css">
#main{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:200px;
    background: lightblue;
}
#hidden {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:280px;
    width:200px;
    background: lightgrey;
    display: none;
}
#hidden2 {
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
    left:580px;
    width:200px;
    background: lightgreen;
    display: none;
}
#hidden3 {
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    left:0px;
    width:200px;
    background: lightpink;
    display: none;
}
</style> 

 <div id="main" onclick="toggle('hidden');toggle('hidden2');toggle('hidden3');">
1
</div> 

 <div id="hidden" onclick="toggle('hidden2');toggle('hidden3');">
1.1
</div> 

 <div id="hidden2"onclick="toggle('hidden3');">
1.1.1
</div> 

 <div id="hidden3">
1.1.1.1
</div>
```

Comment: Does this need to be dynamic?

Comment: @jeff rupert, yes, i want it to be dynamic from mysql.

Comment: Check r00fus's treeviewer option. Looks like it might (on the JS side, at least) do what you want there.

Comment: Do you want this to function AJAX-y? Meaning... an update on the server doesn't require a full page refresh? So, if you hide something, and then show it again, if there's an update, it auto-updates.

Comment: it works when i changed the javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a plugin from a framework like jQuery, Mootools, or ExtJS instead of trying to reinvent the wheel?

It looks like you want a [treeviewer](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/).

btw, you are using javascript, it's not only CSS... please tag javascript as well.

Comment: @r00fus, Thanks, it's an alternative choice for me. but not my ideal one.